# Holder inequality with respect to convex function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, inequalities

Given $a, T>0$, by Holder's inequality we have
$$
\int_T^{T+a}f(s)ds\leq \left(\int_0^{T+a}|f(s)|^2ds\right)^{1/2}\cdot\sqrt{a}.
$$
Do we have similar result if we replace $|x|^2$ by some convex function? That is, let $\Psi$ be a convex function such that $\Psi(x)/|x|\to\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$, do we have
$$
\int_T^{T+a}f(s)ds\leq \int_0^T\Psi(f(s))ds\cdot\Phi(a),
$$
where $\Phi(a)$ goes to 0 as $a\to0$?

Comment: Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Jensen's inequality seems not work. Thanks.

Comment: Just a typo report: in the last line of your question it should be $\Phi(a)$, not $Phi(a)$.

Comment: is everything correct with the limits of integration in right hand side guys? Should not they be $\int_T^{T+a}$ in both inequalities?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is known as Young's (or Hölder's) inequality for Orlicz spaces, and one should take for $\Phi$ the (Legendre) convex conjugate
$$
\Phi(y)=\Psi^*(y)=\sup_x \{ xy-\Psi(x) \}
$$